# How can I use std::lower_bound when I'm only interested in comparing part of the value and can't assume a default constructor for the other part

Tags: c++

Here's what I wish to do. Using a generic sorted container. For associative containers search for a key, find a generic value. For non-associative containers search for key, find nullptr_t nullptr. It would be useful for set intersections between associative and non-associative containers.

I have a search function that should leave &it on the lower bound of a std::pair where i <= it->first.

```
template <typename Iter, typename End>
bool search (unsigned i, Iter& it, End& end) {...}
```

**Here's where I'm stumped.** std::lower_bound's 3rd argument takes a reference to a type. I'm only interested in searching for the value of it->first. Previously I've made a dummy value using a default constructor for value.second, but that seems janked.

std::lower_bound

```
template< class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare >
ForwardIt lower_bound( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, Compare comp );
```

Comment: I really don't understand your question. If you want the comparison to only look at `it->first`, provide a comparer that only looks at `it->first`? What is the problem?

Comment: const &T value in std::lower_bound. What value can I pass if I only have value.first and there is no default constructor for value.second?

Comment: Just pass that first value? The type `T` does not need to match the type of `*first`, so long as the comparer knows how to compare two different types.

Comment: Thanks. I just missed the forest for the trees. Regarding the comparison operator: "The type Type2 must be such that an object of type T can be implicitly converted to Type2"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a heterogeneous comparator *(i.e. one which takes arguments who's types are not the same)* to `lower_bound`. The first argument will come from a dereferenced iterator from the range, the second argument will come from the value passed as the third argument to `lower_bound`. So, you can use something like this:

```
struct Compare
{
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    bool operator()(T1 const& lhs, T2 const& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.first < rhs;
    }
};
```

Then you can call `lower_bound` like this:

```
lower_bound(container.begin(), container.end(), value, Compare());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::lower_bound as follows (in C++14):

```
using T=int;
std::vector<std::pair<unsigned, T> > pairVector;
T searchedValue=1;
std::lower_bound(pairVector.begin(), pairVector.end(), searchedValue
               , [](auto a, auto b) {return a.first < b;} )
```

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) why such a binary function works.

**EDIT**: that is basically the same as the former answer by Benjamin Lindley, just that it uses a lambda closure instead of a pre-defined class. I'll let it stand, though.